# Set filename to Lav Splitter Source filter

Tags: c#, video, streaming, directshow, directshow.net

I am able to render RTP stream over 234.5.6.7:2000 using Lav Splitter Source filter in GraphStudio. When I add the filter, GraphStudio asks for filename or URL as input. That is how I render RTP stream, buth how can I do it in code?

For writing file, I used to do so:

```
(fileWriter as IFileSinkFilter).SetFilename("c:\\a.avi",null);
```

But it is source filter. How should I set filename/URL for source filter (Lav Splitter Source)?

Comment: The same way, URL instead of file path in argument string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAV Splitter (and file source filters) should support [IFileSourceFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. So you just do:

```
(lavSplitter as IFileSourceFilter).Load("c:\\a.avi", null);
```

You can use URL instead of filename here. Also you have to check and handle the *HRESULT* code of *Load()*.

Answer (score 0):

I should set mediatype of **Load** function:

```
AMMEdiaType media = new AMMediaType();
media.majorTpye = MediaType.URLStream;
(lavSplitterSourceFilter as IFileSourceFilter).Load("rtp://234.5.6.7:2000", media);
```

Thank to Anten Angelov